# coverband gem for my application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Am trying to work on coverband gem that will show the code covered in my application. I followed commands from this link https://github.com/danmayer/coverband, and used "rake test" to generate coverage. Added

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start
```

to test/test_helper.rb and config/application.rb as in simplecov gem documentation. My question is how to get output for the entire clicks and adds that i do on my application? For now i end up with output on initializers and configs but i need codes covered for controllers, models and views. 
Would somebody help with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get a working spec/spec_helper.rb configuration that executes SimpleCov correctly simply using the $ rspec spec/ command thanks to a comment on the Github issue that sent me to this blog entry, and its example spec/spec_helper.rb. All reasons why this works are contained in the (very detailed!) blog entry. Replace SampleApp with the name of your application

```
Spork.prefork do
  unless ENV['DRB']
    require 'simplecov'
    SimpleCov.start 'rails'
  end

  require 'rails/application'
  require Rails.root.join("config/application")

  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.mock_with :rspec
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

    config.before :each do
      if Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
      else
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
      end
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end

    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 12):

Hey I am the author of Coverband. I wanted to help make sure people understand that Coverband isn't for test code coverage. For that you should just look at Simplecov which has all you need. Coverband, provides runtime code coverage, which is useful for seeing what code is executed on production servers. This helps find features and code that is being maintained but isn't in use by any actual users. The use case from Simplecov is very different. Coverband uses the Simplecov output formatters, but besides that they don't share other code or the same goals.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using Cucumber with a Web driver. That should get clicks in the coverage report. If you need Javascript evaluation, you'll want to use Selenium.